# How to crop and save a non-rectangular, but polygonal area from a picture box in winforms c#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, crop, picturebox

I want to crop a non-rectangular, but still polygonal area of an image in a picture box in winforms c#. I found many articles on cropping rectangular areas. But how to crop a non rectangular shaped area. I am a dummy with winforms. Can anybody help me please? I want actually to save that cropped area as a seperate image file at the end.

Comment: This might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703519/Cropping-Particular-Region-In-Image-Using-Csharp

Comment: Was I able to help you? Do you need more explanation?

Comment: Thanx a lot. I would try it.

Comment: @Taw Yes, I too think so now. But its question title is not 'appropriate' and much searcheable. So that might be the reason I missed it while searching for hours...!! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot The information u had given was much like a summary. But I used that knowledge with the answer in the link given by Taw. Thanks

Comment: @sab669 The codeproject u had given the link was great. That did my job. I have a problem in it if u have used it. I want to change the background color of cropped images (which is currently set as black in that code.) Do u have any hint on how to do it please??

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used and it and I only barely skimmed reading that before linking it here. Don't know much about it to offer you any guidance.

Comment: Ok. I hope I would try it with the link TaW has provided.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use [System.Drawing.Graphics.Clip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to limit the area to your polygon and then use [System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/558kfzex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to draw the image.